# iOS: Issue in response time of two urls hitting same server

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, iphone, web-services

I am facing issue with two different web Api calls, Both hitting same server and returns same data (Beta and Live url's).
When I hit Live url its responding well, For example if response returns after 5  to 8 seconds same hit with Beta url returns after 20 to 35 seconds. I saw other related questions on stackoverflow but no success. Or its issue on server side ?
Can anyone suggest me suitable solution?
Thanks

Comment: It depends on many factor such as amount of data got from web api call, response time for web api call to reply back, internet connectivity data transfer, hosting server connectivity response time and many other

Comment: its not your fault, its the server. It makes sense to use a poor server for beta processing and a good one for live. So dont bother about it.